# chef(knife): get file with all attributes from all cookbooks

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Could some advice the best way to receive all attributes from all cookbooks. For example I have 10 cookbooks (test1..test10). Each of cookbook have a few files with default attributes (default.rb, test.rb, main.rb, etc). Is there any script (knife command) to receive all attributes in one file (preferably in JSON).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: I don't have a code yet, I've planned to use "knife cookbook show cookbookname latest attributes attributefilename.rb" something like this. But maybe someone have any other ideas/solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in to Chef for this, nor would it really make sense there. Unless you make a ton of assumptions specific to your company or team, the output would be meaningless. Probably write a local Ruby (or whatever) script to do what you need.